# Particle Collision Object for some particles but not others?

Tags: particles, collision

Newb here. I have particles coming from two different emitters inside a sphere. I want the particles from one emitter to collide with the sphere, staying inside it, but I want the particles from the other emitter to pass through the sphere to the outside. Can this be accomplished?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can place particle system and collider objects on multiple and separate layers, and they will only respond to the layer(s) that they are in.

Example blend file:

[image]

Note: The blend file didn't require the objects to be on multiple layers to achieve the requested effect , but just to be complete, to place objects on more than one layer, select the object, press <kbd>m</kbd>, then press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and <kbd>Left Mouse</kbd> click on additional layers.

Can also be done in the *Properties Area > Object tab > Relations* panel.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the "collision group" particle physics setting, that make particles only collide with objects in the same group as the emitter, instead of only colliding with objects on the same layer.